# Groovy in org-mode babel?

Tags: groovy, org-mode

I'm trying to learn Groovy and want to use Emacs org-mode. I've got [Groovy In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/groovy-in-action-second-edition) and am trying to run the very first program in the available source, `Listing_01_01_Gold.groovy`

```
#+begin_src groovy  :results output
List fibo = [1, 1]                          //#A
List gold = [1, 2]                          //#B

while ( ! isGolden( gold[-1] ) ) {          //#C
    fibo.add( fibo[-1] + fibo[-2] )         //#D
    gold.add( fibo[-1] / fibo[-2] )         //#E
}

println "found golden ratio with fibo(${ fibo.size-1 }) as"
println fibo[-1] + " / " + fibo[-2] + " = " + gold[-1]
println "_" * 10 +  "|"  + "_" * (10 * gold[-1])

def isGolden(candidate) {                   //#F
    def small = 1                           //#G
    def big = small * candidate             //#H
    return isCloseEnough( (small+big)/big, big/small)
}

def isCloseEnough(a,b) { return (a-b).abs() < 1.0e-9 }
//#A Initial Fibonacci numbers
//#B Golden ration candidates
//#C Last gold candidate
//#D Next fibo number
//#E Next golden candidate
//#F Candidate satisfies golden rule
//#G Smaller section
//#H Bigger section
#+end_src
```

which gives this error

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "groovy-31624d60$isGolden" in class file groovy-31624d60$isGolden
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "groovy-31624d60$isGolden" in class file groovy-31624d60$isGolden
    at groovy-31624d60.run(groovy-31624d60:4)
```

I can very well imagine that I've done something stupid, but with no docs, I'm just guessing. Simple things, however, have worked:

```
#+begin_src groovy :results raw
today = new Date()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
Tue Feb 20 15:44:50 EST 2018
```

Not sure what to do. But then `>groovysh Listing_01_01_Gold.groovy`, i.e., in a terminal won't run either, only `>groovy Listing_01_01_Gold.groovy`. So obviously I'm missing something basic here....

Comment: Bug in ob-groovy.el, I would guess.

Comment: With Racket, it fires up a geiser-mode REPL buffer on a code block C-c C-c and from then on you're dealing with that "session" REPL. But `groovy` and `groovysh` seem to be two separate worlds, i.e, there is no REPL buffer springing to life...

Comment: I submitted a patch and the maintainer has accepted it and applied it. It should be available from ELPA on 2018-02-26 as part of the stable release, but it's also available in both the maintenance branch and the master (development) branch from the org-mode git repository.

Comment: ob-groovy.el does not support sessions. And it does not use groovysh at all.

Answer (score 0):

It objects to the dash in the file name: groovy-31624d60.

All you need to do is change the dash to an underscore on line 87 of ob-groovy.el:

```
(pcase result-type
  (`output
   (let ((src-file (org-babel-temp-file "groovy_")))   ;;; <---HERE
     (progn (with-temp-file src-file (insert body))
          (org-babel-eval
           (concat org-babel-groovy-command " " src-file) ""))))
  (`value ...
```

I don't understand why they use backticks instead of quotes either.

EDIT: there is a second dash-to-underscore replacement needed for "value" output, a few lines further down in the file.

Comment: Thanks. It corrected the first error, but gives a new error: `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy_25984y_W.isCloseEnough() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigDecimal) values: [1.5, 2]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy_25984y_W.isCloseEnough() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigDecimal) values: [1.5, 2]
 at groovy_25984y_W.isGolden(groovy_25984y_W:16)
 at groovy_25984y_W$isGolden.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 at groovy_25984y_W.run(groovy_25984y_W:4)`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html ... maybe thinking they might need to do something internal later ... since regular and back are the same, perhaps...

Comment: Not sure what causes the second error: I cannot reproduce it in my setup.